# IE issues with Drop Down menus

Tags: html, css

I have coded that template to be installed in some sort of CMS. Here is the link http://amtcdiecasting.com/demo/cobb-county/.
It's menus and sub-menus are not working in IE and on the other side they are perfect in all other browsers.
I have also deleted the sub menus but it still don't works as it is in Chrome and FF.
Design after deleting sub menus :
http://amtcdiecasting.com/demo/cobb-county-new/

Comment: Working fine for me, IE9, 10 and 11.

Comment: @Niet: Sir the problem is with IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used HTML5 tags for menu(nav). that will no support below IE8 version.

Use normal HTML tags (link div ,span , p, ul , li) to make menu instead of HTML5 tags. It will support in IE 7, 8 also.

Comment: Its not working. I am using IE 8 it hides all the elements on that page except the background of the main wrapper.
Please have a look:
http://amtcdiecasting.com/demo/cobb-county-new/

Comment: yeah its done. Thankyou.
Another Question: Why clients insist to use IE when on the other side the whole world is using chrome and FF. lol..:)

Comment: Because IE is the default browser for Windows and some people don't care to change it.